# selecting recently added data using joins in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In this i am trying to display the user details including users payment details,
I have the table like userpayment and userdetails.

userpayment table consists of fields like `paymentid,userid,paidamount,planid,planname,validmonths,validupto,createdat`

userdetails table consists of 
`userid,username,dob,address,gender,mobile,createdat`.

In userdetails table, every entry is an unique one.But in userpayment table single user can have multiple payment details.I need to fetch the details of every users including users payment payment details,record of payment details must be unique one and it must be recently inserted one.

I am using codeigniter,

My query is,

```
$res=$this->db->query(select * from userdetails r,userpayment p where r.userid all (\"select userid from userpayment GROUP BY userid HAVING max(paymentid) \")");
```

Please correct it if there is any mistakes in my query and give solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from userdetails where 
userid = (select userid from paymentdetails order by createdat desc limit 1)
```

Comment: thank you for your help,i don't need very most recently added record of whole table. I need recently added record for each and  every individual userid.